# @helper and Url.Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to extract some simple code into a separate helper function

```
    @helper ShowPath()
    {
    <p class="migas">
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">Home</a>
   &gt; <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "AboutUs")">About Us</a>
   &gt; Directory</p>
}
```

Works fine within the original cshtml file but the @Url.Action causes a compile error when I extract it to a separate file that I put within the App_Code folder.

Do I need to pass in a HTMLHelper from the calling page? If so, any ideas how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to pass the `UrlHelper` to your method

```
@helper ShowPath(UrlHelper url)
{
    <p class="migas">
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">Home</a>
   &gt; <a href="@url.Action("Index", "AboutUs")">About Us</a>
   &gt; Directory</p>
}
```

and then from a view,

```
@YouAppCodeName.ShowPath(Url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@using System.Web.Mvc
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html

@helper ShowPath(WebViewPage page)
{
  <p class="migas">
  <a href="@page.Url.Action("Index", "Home")">Home</a>
  &gt; <a href="@page.Url.Action("Index", "AboutUs")">About Us</a>
  &gt; Directory</p>
}
```

When you call it on the page send *this* as an argument. It can give you access to all the helpers if you need them in future.